# List-initialization to Fixed-Sized C-Array zeroes unused indices

Tags: c++, list-initialization

I have a constructor that looks like

```
A (const int(&inArr)[4])
{
  ...
}
```

And I can construct an instance with list-initialization as such,

```
A a({3,4,5,6});
```

However, I can also construct an instance with a shorter list, e.g. `{3,2}`, or an empty list `{}`. From my testing in MSVC and Clang, the array received by the constructor is always zeroed after the values in the list. i.e. `{3,2}` will be read as `[3,2,0,0]`, and `{}` as `[0,0,0,0]`.

I am wondering if this is standard behaviour that can be relied upon, or if this may vary across platforms/compilers?

Comment: This is the expected behavior.  Finding a duplicate now

Comment: @NathanOliver many thanks, I couldn't find the magic words